# ZF2 Model used in many modules using zend global config

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have a Class object which is used in many modules in my zend structure :

```
/module/
--|Aplication
--|MyClassModule
----|config
----|src
------|Factory
------|Model
---------|> MyObjectClass.php 
----Module.php
--|AnotherModule
```

So my idea is to use this MyObjectClass.php in other modules so I can avoid duplication and have its own configuration. So far, for this is ok, however I want to get the variables set from my **config/autoload** files injected in this class but I don't know how.

How can I load this config data into my class model? Which is the best approach ? I can load it by accessing this directly but I don't think this is very elegant

e.g: `$configArray = require './config/autoload/config.local.php';`

I am not very experienced with zend so I dont know where to start with. I have seen many tutorials of how to do this via controllers, views.. etc but not in specific classes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

All config files are merged into one config, when your ZF2 application is bootstrapped. That includes local.php, global.php from `config/autoload` and all used modules' module.config.php. With a bit of more research, you can overwrite the standard loading, e.g. loading custom configs.

After bootstrapping, your are able to access the config from the `ServiceManager`. There are preserved keys for some ZF2-specific configs, service_manager, etc.

```
$serviceManager->get('config');
```

There is a "standard" service pattern in ZF2: `Factory`. This can be applied for Controllers, Services. What ever you want.

```
namespace Application\Factory;

use Application\Model\MyObjectClass;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class MyObjectFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * Create service
     *
     * @param ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        // get some config parameter, inject it into model
        $config = $serviceLocator->get('config');

        $myObjectClass = new MyObjectClass();
        // ... e.g. $myObjectClass->setConfig($config);
        return $myObjectClass;
    }
}
```

It should be clear, what this factory is made for: create and return an instance of your custom object ;) You may configure your instance with some config params. With `ServiceLocator` as method param, you are able to access the config, other services etc.

Further, you have to register your own service/factory in the `factories` section of `service_manager` config in your module's module.config.php:

```
return array(
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'MyObjectFactory' => 'Application\Factory\MyObjectFactory',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Now you should be able to access your factory, e.g. in an `ActionController` or wherever you have access to `ServiceManager`. That means, you can also access this factory from different modules.

```
public function someCustomAction() {
    $myObjectClass = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('MyObjectFactory');
    $myObjectClass2 = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('MyObjectFactory');

    var_dump($myObjectClass);
    var_dump($myObjectClass2);

    if ($myObjectClass === $myObjectClass2) {
        echo '<br />equal';
    }

    $myObjectClass = new MyObjectClass();
    $myObjectClass2 = new MyObjectClass();

    var_dump($myObjectClass);
    var_dump($myObjectClass2);
}
```

**Note:**
Be aware, that `ServiceManager` returns the same instance of your object.  So, that seems like what you ask for? In contrast, creating a new instance will create different objects.

**Note 2:**
Tested with ZF2 v2.4.9

Comment: Beware `$this->getServiceLocator()` in controllers has been depreciated in ZF2.5 and removed in 3.0. Consider injecting your models into your controller instead.